# PHP: are rand() pseudo generated numbers always the same for a given seed supplied?

Tags: php, random, number-sequence

I'm generating a sequence of pseudo random numbers with this code:

```
$seed = 1;
srand( $seed );
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    echo rand(0,100) . "\n";
}
exit(0);
```

The following code outputs always (on my machine)

```
84
39
79
[....]
77
28
55
```

Can I rely on the fact that the output of the above code will be always the same?

If not, what could make it change?

For example may different versions of PHP give different results?

Or PHP running on different operative systems?

Comment: [Same seed same numbers](https://3v4l.org/N2nCO)

Comment: Not sure if 32-bit/64-bit PHP would give variation

Comment: @MarkBaker Seems not to be the case: [32bit](https://eval.in/480799) [64bit](https://3v4l.org/X24sH)

Comment: Nope, just tested it myself, no difference between 32-bit and 64-bit

Comment: Though I'm running it on Windows, and I get a sequence of 99, 38, 79, 21, 75, 91, 42, 36, 47, 67.... so it may be that's OS will vary it. It's consistent against all versions, 32-bit or 64-bit on my Windows box, whereas if I run it on a Linux box I consistently get the same sequence of numbers as your 3v4l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I run this code on Windows, I get a sequence of 99, 38, 79, 21, 75, 91, 42, 36, 47, 67. It's consistent against all versions, 32-bit or 64-bit on my Windows box.

Whereas if I run it on a Linux box I consistently get a sequence of 84, 39, 79, 80, 92, 19, 33, 77, 28, 55 no matter what version of PHP

So it isn't consistent between Operating Systems

---

However, if I use `mt_srand()` and `mt_rand()` instead of `srand()` and `rand()` then I do get consistence between Windows/Linux and different versions of PHP from 5.2 to 7.0

```
$seed = 1;
mt_srand( $seed );
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    echo mt_rand(0,100) . "\n";
}
exit(0);
```

consistently gives 58, 0, 72, 94, 100, 87, 70, 100, 86, 76

Comment: Warning, if memory serves right, it is NOT even consistent across different php versions.

Comment: yup, 
Output for 5.2.1 - 7.0.0: 580729410087701008676
Output for 4.3.0 - 5.2.0: 89985189699593497888

-- http://3v4l.org

Comment: Of course, if anybody is still using PHP <= 5.2.0 then they really should be ungrading, at least to a supported version

Comment: Have fun next time PHP alters the mt_rand scheme, and your program/database depend on the old scheme, and you have to rewrite the old mt_rand in userland PHP :)

Comment: @MarkBaker the accepted answer is not correct, as other people have pointed out. I've got 23,25,37,100,100,95,72,14,49,84

Answer (score 2):

There's no guarantee between random numbers being the same across OS's or PHP versions. So best bet is to create your own psuedo random number generator, as pointed out in this [blog post](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-random-number-generator/)

Here's the code:

```
<?php

class Random {

    // random seed
    private static $RSeed = 0;

    // set seed
    public static function seed($s = 0) {
        self::$RSeed = abs(intval($s)) % 9999999 + 1;
        self::num();
    }

    // generate random number
    public static function num($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        if (self::$RSeed == 0) self::seed(mt_rand());
        self::$RSeed = (self::$RSeed * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$RSeed % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }

}

// set seed
Random::seed(42);

// echo 10 numbers between 1 and 100
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo Random::num(1, 100) . ',';
}
echo "\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo Random::num() . ',';
}
echo "\n";
```

Which results in:

```
76,86,14,79,73,2,87,43,62,7,
393758,1684299,822150,2105442,337168,202955,203548,277673,1154689,1729772,
```

And obviously you'll get consistent results between different PHP versions. Note that you *must* provide a seed, otherwise this function will fall back on `mt_rand` and then you're at the mercy of the OS again!